# How do I connect to a Cogent CSD200 fingerprint scanner using Java?

Tags: java, sdk, fingerprint

Are there any SDKs or libraries available which can help me to interact with this scanner?

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: I'm trying to build a fingerprint-based authentication java application. I have bought a Cogent CSD200 fingerprint scanner and installed its driver.  Now I want to know how do I interact with this fingerprint scanner in java.
Haven't started building the application, just want to test how to interact with this scanner.

Comment: Check if it came with a documentation for its API. That will help you to know how to call the methods defined for use with interacting with this fingerprint device. It is easier to try out examples in the API document of the device.

Comment: @JosephMwema I tried searching for its API documentation. Here is the [the product information](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/769516O/3m-csd-200i-single-digit-optical-fingerprint-scanner.pdf?fn=3M%E2%84%A2%20CSD%20200i%20Single-digit%20Optica)

It specifies that FPCaptureAccess is the SDK that can be used but I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: After I installed its driver I found these files in C drive. Can these .dll files help me in any case? I don't really know what these files are and how to use them in java. [IMG](http://i66.tinypic.com/34q3ejn.png)

Comment: Yes. Those are the files you need especially the *.DLL SDK files. Just look for information on how to import  *.dll into your visual studio project. Also find info on how to know contents of a DLL so that you can begin to figure out how to go about what to use in your project.

Comment: NVM, I contacted the device vendor and he provided the SDK along with documentations finally. Thanks anyways for the interaction :)

Comment: I am just purchased the same model fingerprint scanner. i need this sdk for my android device. can you please share to my email id tamilairy@gmail.com. Thanks in advance

Comment: @DevendraChouhan , I am using the same device , can you share some sample how to access it programmatically

Comment: @DevendraChouhan I mentioned that i allready have SDK and documnets , it does not mention any event of this device

Comment: @DevendraChouhan Can you share the FPCaptureAccess sdk. Since I also have the same finger print scanner and facing the same issue as you. Thank you

Comment: @Saurabh Did you get it resolved ?

Comment: @Lokesh , yes Its working

Comment: @Saurabh how did you check the template quality? I have gone through documentation and it's all in dll . How did you verify the template quality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching finally got it.
[Driver and SDK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2AzJvuYUUMfWDVDcE9McE1Salk).
I have written a sample GUI based java program to interact with the scanner.
Here is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DevendraKumarL/0f958c8dddde54c9d5c91439642e7f9f)

Running on Eclipse:

Import the java program into eclipse and add the SDK jar, this can be found after installing the SDK (setup.exe) present inside the folder `3MCogent-CSD200-SDK-v2.7 Setup` found in the above google drive link.

Remember to install the driver for the scanner before running. For instructions follow the readme in `3M Cogent CSD 200 Driver` folder in the above google drive link.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: In FPCaptureAccess sdk documentation says we need CG4EssentialsApi.h and CG4EssentialsApiM.h file to acquire finger prints. I didn't get those header files in the link you have shared.

Comment: @Devendra Chouhan  I want to use it with Linux API.  Do you know where I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

The above google driver link is broken. Can you please send the DRIVER and SDK. I not able to find it anywhere online.